# How to install RVM on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows-7, rvm

How do I install RVM on Windows 7?

It says to install RVM, and use the following script:

```
user$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

But I have no idea what to do with it. If I type it into cmd an error message comes up saying it was 'unexpected at this time'.

What do I do to install RVM?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No RVM for you! From [RVM’s FAQ](https://rvm.io/support/faq#does-rvm-work-on-windows-will-it-in-the-future):

> ### Does RVM work on windows? Will it in the future?
>
> NO. If you would like to manage multiple versions of ruby on windows please use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) which is an excellent tool by Gordon Thiesfeld. You can find it on GitHub. There are [plans to include windows support in RVM 2.0](https://www.bountysource.com/fundraisers/489-rvm-2-0).

Comment: For all the DRY people go on and on about in the Ruby community, they sure seem keen to keep two different tools which have exactly the same purpose.

Comment: YES -  there is a way to do this now: http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/

Comment: @Trejkaz: DRY means "don't repeat yourself". It says nothing about not repeating *others* :)

Comment: An alternative is my free program RubySwitcher (written in C#) available from http://pessetto.com/pages/Software.  It has a simple GUI to it.  May require additional Microsoft Redistributables.

Comment: I really wish this position was featured more prominently on RVM's website.  Just wasted a couple hours because [this page on RVM's site](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) says to use [this tutorial](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) which is pretty old and sure didn't work for me.What's worse, [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is no longer maintained.

Comment: Pik says to use Uru: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru. I'm considering using Docker.

Answer (score 6):

Pik is an RVM for windows
pik is a tool to manage multiple versions of ruby on Windows. It can be used from the Windows command line (cmd.exe), Windows PowerShell, or Git Bash.
follow this link [pik on windows](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik)

Comment: Just to add context to those coming across this.  Pik is no longer maintained according to it's GitHub repository: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik

Answer (score 4):

Currently [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is no longer maintained use **[uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru)** an alternative to pik

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed i think we can use cygwin for having RVM on windows

Link: http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

you can install pik trough chocolatey
https://chocolatey.org/packages/pik

Answer (score 0):

RVM supports most UNIX like systems and Windows (with Cygwin or Bash on Ubuntu on Windows).
https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Bash on Ubuntu on Windows works fine for me.