# Curl Not a Reconized Command Ruby RVM

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM and I'm following the instructions from the RVM webpage. It says to use this command in the cmd:

```
     curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

But it says that 'curl' is not a reconized command:

```
     'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     operable program or batch file.
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you running Windows?

Comment: That error message is from Windows. Unfortunately RVM doesn't work with Windows.

Comment: Oh well then thats the problem I have windows. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows doesn't come with the 'curl' command built-in.  You can download it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console).  But that isn't going to help you much, because RVM doesn't support Windows :)

You can use [pik](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/pik/) instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was just about to add. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12910824/2141283 pik will do the trick.