# trying to install railsintaller and having problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow Hartl's ruby tutorial and use railsinstaller. I'm a beginner and have downloaded the rails setup files. A command prompt comes up with the following C:\Sites>

It asked for my name and email previously, but now I'm not sure how to proceed with installing ruby, git, etc. I am perusing the Google Group but am not finding how to do it so wanted to reach out to the community.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would reccomend whole-heartedly against developing Rails on windows. Use a Unix based system, you'll save so much pain!

Comment: hmm..can you elaborate. I am very new to this process and developing/technology. any insight is appreciated. assuming, that i am unable to go w unix (i am using my work laptop for a non tech field)

Comment: Basically, Rails development is much easier if you use a Mac or Linux. Use tools such as RVM to manage Ruby installations.

Comment: If you have got to command prompt showing `C:\Sites`, it is quite likely you have everything installed already. Try running `ruby -v` and see what output it shows.

Comment: Quick question: How do I accesss the C:\Sites prompt after I close the command window and then reopen a new command window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RailsInstaller automatically installs Ruby, Git, and practically everything you need for you. Your entering of your name and email was actually for the Git installation; Rails doesn't need that. Type in 'git' (without the quotes) and you should find that it's already installed.

Comment: hey all very helpful...i am also looking through RailsGuides which is corroborating what you guys are saying

Comment: Quick question: How do I accesss the C:\Sites prompt after I close the command window and then reopen a new command window

Comment: what prompt do you see when you reopen the window?

Comment: Hi - when I do a simple run>cmd.exe..the first prompt says C:\User\myusername>

Comment: So you have to change directories. To exit a directory you do cd .. So, to get to where you want, you'd do cd ..\..\Sites       --To see more about how to use the command prompt, see: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your patience with my level of knowledge.

Comment: I believe I successfully have git and ruby (v2). However, I did not know how to install RVM - https://rvm.io/rvm/install

How do I type that in - I ask because I' m not sure if I have successfully installed Ruby Gems. When I type in rails --version I get a list of items but I'm not sure if its correct and I don't think it is (I can PM a printscreen)...in particular I do not seem to know how to run the bundler either

Comment: Unfortunately, RVM cannot be installed on Windows, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845432/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-7