# Installing Ruby Version Manager

Tags: ruby, rvm

For a complete beginner - how do I proceed with installing Ruby Version Manager

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

I tried typing in the first line into the command prompt but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should ellaborate, maybe show us your input.

Comment: What did you type in / what was the output / what operating system are you on?

Comment: RVM is only for Linux and Mac OS. I don't know what operating system you are on, but if you are on Windows, an alternative is pik: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik

Comment: Hi I'm using windows for OS. I just opened a command prompt and it opens with C:\Users\myusername>

I typed in the first line from the install. THe reply I got was '\curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command , operable program or batch file. I am a bit lost

Comment: Ahh...ok thanks I am on Windows so that explains a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you should try http://railsinstaller.org/, there are versions for Windows and for OSX.

Comment: I believe I successfully have git and ruby (v2). But, I' m not sure if I have successfully installed Ruby Gems. When I type in rails --version I get a list of items; I'm not sure if its correctly installed and I don't think it is (I can PM a printscreen)...in particular I do not seem to know how to run the bundler either . Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I've been told I can't use this on Windows before you responded

Comment: you can use railsisntaller on windows and it has a support irc channel here: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=railsinstaller

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845432/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-7) your answer would be [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik). Note you might also find this [article](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2010/07/28/ruby-version-manager-for-windows/) helpful.