# mac os - Gem giving Connection Reset while downloading Rails Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

Ruby version is 2.5.1 and gem version is 2.7.7 both updated today. OpenSSL is 1.0.2 also updated today. 
When i run

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.0
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 5.2.0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have checked all GitHub issues and none of them had a solution. I added certificates to keychain and to the openSSL folder and nothing has seemed to work. Any ideas?

I have also checked my router and computer firewalls

Comment: Can you check the version compatibility of OpenSSL(1.0.2) and Ruby (2.5.1)? Maybe you need to update the OpenSSL version.

Comment: @ApurvaMayank I have the latest openSSL version and the versions are both compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132450/error-installing-bundler#19206499) and try:

```
$ rvm -v
# rvm 1.19.1 (stable)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
# Certificates for...
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
# Updating certificates...
```

Comment: but do you have rvm certificates up to date? can you show what `rvm osx-ssl-certs status all` yields?

Comment: Ok i got it, when i run the command it yields this:    `cURL certificate bundle /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt not found`

Comment: Well i dont know what happened but after that I ran `gem install rails` and got it to work. Thank you!