# installing gem install zurb-foundation on windows - getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to install: gem install zurb-foundation on windows 7 and I get this error in the command prompt:

[image: error message]

I am running Ruby 2.0.0p247 and tried to update rails but it did not need an update.

I am not sure how to interpret the message... help much appreciated.

I also got the same exact message trying to install compass

Comment: It seems your Internet connection is not working....!!

Comment: My connection appears to be fine as I am online... it did a ruby version check and ran the rails update check without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will help you for SSL certificate error:

As referred to below link:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/676-cannot-install-foundation-gem

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

**If you are using RVM:**

```
rvm get stable

rvm osx-ssl-certs update all

rvm rubygems latest
```

**OR**

```
gem update --system
```

**Update**

As given to below link:

[Curl Certificate Error when Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2)

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

Comment: The command replied: latest version already installed Aborting.

Comment: i do not have rvm... what is it?

Comment: Ruby Version Manager, using RVM you can run multiple versions of ruby on same system..

Comment: Here is for windows 7 similar to RVM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845432/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-7

Comment: thanks for your help... think i found what I need... going to have to play with it... really appreciate your assistance