# When I try to run "rails s" or "rails server" command I get an error and It does not let me start the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Once I install rails then I got into a folder and type in `rails new app`. Then I go into the folder and run `bundle install`. Once I have installed all the necessary gems I go into the applications folder and i type in either

```
rails s
```

or

```
rails server
```

and I get the following error:

```
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri
.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32
/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32
/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/l
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/l
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `<module:Helper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sp
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/ra
ils/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/ra
ils/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/ra
ils.rb:11:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/ra
ils.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass-ra
ils.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass-ra
ils.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler.rb
:134:in `require'
        from C:/RubyProjects/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how can I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: if you are using windows machine Nokogiri doesn't support ruby 2.2 on windows yet. For more info you can see [this answer in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999906/require-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-loaderror-when-running)

Comment: Hey I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and I also tried it out with ruby 2.1 and I got the same issue. I'm not completely sure if I should delete 2.2 before that though... How would I be able to test it out on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you for now or until Nokogiri release new version with windows support.

**Solution-1:**

Change your development platform to linux or it's flavours like Ubuntu.

**Solution-2:**

Downgrade your ruby version to 2.1 or lower. Once Nokogiri release new version with windows support then you can upgrade ruby to 2.2 .
To downgrade ruby versions use RVM or similar tool to maintain/manage the ruby versions. But I am not sure RVM will work on Windows platform you can refer this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845432/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-7) .