# How to create `jekyll new project` with specific jekyll version on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, version-control, rubygems, jekyll

I have ruby 2.1.6 and 2.1.7 installed on my PC (Win 7 x64 SP1) and I use [`uru`](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru) to switch between them. They work fine.

I also have installed a few Jekyll versions: 2.4.0, 2.5.3, 3.0.2 and 3.1.1. I work with some jekyll projects with no trouble at all.

Now, in order to reproduce a very specific website, I need to create a `jekyll new project` with a Jekyll specific version.

- I tried running `uru 216` -> `jekyll -v 2.4.0 new project` and didn't work. The terminal response is `jekyll 3.1.1`.
- I also tried `jekyll new project -v 2.4.0` and didn't work either - the response was `new`.

## **Is there a way of doing that?**

---

Or the only way is running `jekyll new project` then adding a `Gemfile` specifying the jekyll version, as in:

`Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'jekyll', '2.4.0'
```

Then running `bundle install` and serving jekyll with Bundler via `bundle exec jekyll serve`?

---

Or perhaps I'll need to install a third ruby version (like 2.1.8) with just `jekyll 2.4.0` to be able to do that?

---

I know about [RVM](https://rvm.io/) and it seems it would do the job, but as far as I know I can't use it because [it doesn't work on Win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845432/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-7/#answer-8845445).

---

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your Gemfile with whatever jekyll version in it

`bundle install`

`bundle exec jekyll new . --force`

`.` means the current folder and `--force` will create a new jekyll even if the folder is not empty

Comment: Thanks for replying! hmmm!! So I create a root folder first, then I add the `Gemfile` and finally I run `bundle exec jekyll new . --force` ? What is the meaning of `. --force`? Is that it the command to force the version-controlled installation?

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna test it and get back to you!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!